# Getting the position of eyelids in C++ using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been puzzling with this problem a while now. I can successfully track the pupil and the iris but I also need to determine if an eyelid covers (and by how much) the iris or not. I've tried thresholding but because the eyelashes vary person to person and the location of the iris might not be centered it can't get an accurate reading. Canny edge detection also can get a bit messy because it will get a lot of edges that will interrupt (i.e. going up and down from pupils center until an edge is found) the desired result.

Pictures: 
Original: 
[image]

Need to find (pupil and iris already found) --> (yellow line)
[image]

Comment: Example of the final result I'm going after: http://imgur.com/a/lBWoF

Comment: Can you add a few more cases?

Comment: If you mean more images: http://imgur.com/a/A74Mm

Comment: May be you could try doing contour detection on the images.

Comment: I tried it but I couldn't find a desirable result... for example: http://imgur.com/a/ncrkm

Comment: I tried some edge detection on the image here and other test images you added in the link. It is tricky to get a robust algorithm for all your test cases. But, I would suggest that you do canny edge detection in the image with a threshold range 50-150 and try to detect curved lines. Once you have that, you can extract the required part of the image. For [curved line detection](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)

Comment: Thank you... will try later :)